# Retrieving calculated field's formula?

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

Is there a ways to read the formula of a calculated column with T-SQL in SQL Server?

I have tried following but it does not work:

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'Formula')
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'Tablename'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE FormulaTable(i INT ,j INT ,k AS i*j+10)


SELECT cc.definition 
FROM sys.computed_columns AS cc 
WHERE cc.name='k'
```

Output:

```
definition
-------------------------------------
([i]*[j]+(10))
```

Comment: What about Views? i.e. I have a view column let's say (Case columnName WHEN 1 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NotOK' END) AS VIEWColumnName. Can I retiriev its definition some way?